# Setting Foreign Keys with SQLAlchemy for FastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have the following tables in my models module and I have to set Foreign Key relations between some of their attributes. However, I am failing.

```
class Exercise(Base):
   __tablename__= "Exercise"
   id=Column(Integer, primary_key= True) 
   name=Column(VARCHAR(250))
   animation_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Animation.id')) #foreign key -> animation.id
   animation=relationship("Animation", back_populates="exercise")
   

class Animation(Base):
   __tablename__="Animation"
   id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,index=True,autoincrement=True)
   name=Column(VARCHAR(250))
   description=Column(VARCHAR(250))
   exercise=relationship("Exercise", back_populates="animation")
```

Im trying to create a relationship between Exercise.animation_id and Animation.id.
I tried adding ForeignKey('Animation.id')) as in the code but it did not work.

I can't think of anything else.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "it did not work"? Do you get an error?

Comment: The code works without errors but FKs do NOT work.
Nothing extra ordinary on console either.

Comment: By chance are you using SQLite?

Comment: Fixed the issue by switching InnoDB from MyISAM. Turns out MyISAM does NOT support foreign keys.

Comment: @GordThompson I have the same problem and use SQLite. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: @ikreb - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by switching to InnoDB from MyISAM. Turns out MyISAM does NOT support foreign keys.

```
class Exercise(Base):
    __tablename__= "Exercise"
    __table_args__= {
        'mysql_engine':'InnoDB'
    }
```